# createUser doesn't work on Firebase/Auth + Next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm working on email + password authentication on Firebase Auth + Next js. But I would like to use a dedicated uid for authentication this time. So I think I should use `createUser` better than `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. However, the error occurs like below:

> Property 'createUser' does not exist on type 'Auth'.

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

      const auth = getAuth()
      const newId = XXXXXXXXXXXXXx 
     
      getAuth()
      .createUser({
        uid: newId,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
      })
      .then((userRecord) => {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
      });

      // It works
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password)
```

Answer (score 0):

To `createUser` you need to use [firebase-admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/).

With `node.js`, install it with `npm install firebase-admin`. Then:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const newId = XXXXXXXXXXXXXx;

admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: newId,
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password,
})
.then(function(userRecord) {
  // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
  console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
});
```

See [Admin SKD user reference for more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).